# not able to format and assign date in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date, datepicker, momentjs

I am working on a react app where I have to format a date in `DD-MM-YYYY` format and send it as a param to my api.

Here's my code:

```
    const params = this.props.listParams;
    const startDate = params.start_date.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    const endDate = params.end_date.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    params.start_date = startDate;
    params.end_date = endDate;
    console.log(startDate, endDate);
```

`listParams` structure:

```
const defaultListParams = {
  start_date: '',
  end_date: '',
  msg_id: '',
  page_num: 1,
  page_size: 5,
};
```

Here `listParams` has all the parameters for my api,start_date and end_Date both are moment objects inside `listParams`. I am formatting and assiging them to startDate and endDate variables and its working but when I reassign it back to `params.start_date` and `params.end_date` I get the following error:

```
index.js?bbc4:258 Uncaught TypeError: date.get is not a function
    at get$1 (index.js?bbc4:258)
    at getMonth (index.js?bbc4:366)
    at DatePicker.componentWillReceiveProps (index.js?bbc4:2450)
    at callComponentWillReceiveProps (react-dom.development.js?7f13:13389)
    at updateClassInstance (react-dom.development.js?7f13:13599)
    at updateClassComponent (react-dom.development.js?7f13:16989)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js?7f13:18502)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js?7f13:348)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js?7f13:398)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js?7f13:455)
```

I am not able to figure out whats the errors.Any leads will be appreaciated.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from assigning values to your props again, you assign string value to `start_date` and `end_date`.

`format()` gives you a string representation of the moment object.

From what I understand more from your error log is that you pass this string to your datepicker which wants parameters as `Date` or `Moment` objects probably.

So, if for example `params.start_date` is a string, then you need to construct `Moment` object like `moment(params.start_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD')`. If it is a `Moment` object (I assume so because you don't get any error about `format()`),  then you don't need to use `format()`.

Answer (score 0):

Because you attempted to change values from `props` which are not writable.

See this: [Props are Read-Only](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#props-are-read-only)

Comment: but I am assigning my props value to params first and then assigning it

Comment: You give the pointer of `this.props.listParams` to `params`, right? So `params.start_date = startDate;` means `this.props.listParams.start_date  = startDate;`. Actually, you could pass setter which use to change startDate and endDate for your father component to props. Always remember that react is a framwork which use **single direction data flow**.

Answer (score 0):

I would highly suggest you to provide some more code, because your error is `date.get is not a function` , but you don't provide us the date and the get method. I think it is because you're trying to call the .get on something that it can't be called on. Moreover try to console.log(date) to see what this date is (:. And comment back

Comment: No date.get is defined nowhere,thats why I am confused with this error

Comment: Moreover, why the is the name defaultListParams and not listParams? Maybe smth has to do with that? Plus, did you maybe try to initialize the date as  a new Date() to make it an object and call the functions on it?

Comment: no,defaultparamslist is in redux reducer and I am assigning it as listParams in initial state